# User cancelled file download in Grails

Tags: grails

How to properly handle a cancelled file download? The file in question is a pretty large zip file that takes a long time to build, so the user has plenty of time to hit the Cancel button on his download dialog window.

When it happens, a nasty Exception occurs (see below), which is expected, since the client broke the pipe. But how to clean it up? Where/What's the proper way to catch the Exception so that the tomcat logs are not littered with them?

Thank you.

The download code itself is pretty standard code from the textbook:

```
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream

def getZipFile(params) {   
  response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"filename.zip\"");
  response.contentType = "application/zip"

  def zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.outputStream)
  zos = functionThatCreatesTheZipFile(zos, params) // this takes some time
  zos.close()
}
```

Exception:

```
rfpmgr [2013-05-01 10:14:32.337] ERROR: web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver IOException occurred when processing request: [GET] /rfpManager/report/downloadZipFile
Stacktrace follows:
java.io.IOException
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.writeBytes(ZipOutputStream.java:617)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.writeCEN(ZipOutputStream.java:501)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.finish(ZipOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:238)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.close(ZipOutputStream.java:360)
at gov.usgs.eventManager.ZipService.getZipFile(ZipService.groovy:32)
at gov.usgs.eventManager.ReportController$_closure18.doCall(ReportController.groovy:738)
at gov.usgs.jdt.josso.spring.JOSSOProcessingFilter.doFilter(JOSSOProcessingFilter.java:144)
at gov.usgs.jdt.josso.agent.GenericServletSSOAgentFilter.doFilter(GenericServletSSOAgentFilter.java:431)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
rfpmgr [2013-05-01 10:14:32.354] ERROR: web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /rfpManager/report/downloadZipFile
getOutputStream() has already been called for this response. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at gov.usgs.jdt.josso.spring.JOSSOProcessingFilter.doFilter(JOSSOProcessingFilter.java:144)
at gov.usgs.jdt.josso.agent.GenericServletSSOAgentFilter.doFilter(GenericServletSSOAgentFilter.java:431)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
at gsp_rfpManager_errorserrors_gsp.run(gsp_rfpManager_errorserrors_gsp.groovy:17)
... 3 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work just fine:

```
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream
import org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException

def getZipFile(params) {   
  response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"filename.zip\"");
  response.contentType = "application/zip"

  try {
    def zos = new ZipOutputStream(response.outputStream)
    zos = functionThatCreatesTheZipFile(zos, params) // this takes some time
    zos.close()
  }
  catch (ClientAbortException ex) {
    println "user aborted download"
  }
}
```

Comment: So I didn't have to include tomcat in my path I caught the IOException

Answer (score 0):

I can see there:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

This is common for Grails controllers when directly rendering things. Solutions:

```
render ( file: <InputStream>, contentType: 'image/jpeg')
//or
render ( file: <byte[]>, contentType: 'image/jpeg')
//or
GrailsWebRequest webRequest = 
             (GrailsWebRequest) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
webRequest.setRenderView(false)
```

That should help.