# Grails Export : getOutputStream() has already been called for this response. Stacktrace follows:

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am using same code for every module (items, products, ....) to export PDF. All places working fine, but one place, the PDF file creating and downloading successfully but in the console it giving error like this.

```
getOutputStream() has already been called for this response. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(FilterServletResponseWrapper.java:121)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:199)
    at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:134)
    at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:150)
    at com.****.***.RoomController$_closure2.doCall(RoomController.groovy:78)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:117)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:233)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:197)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:171)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-05-06 17:38:54,381 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-5] GrailsExceptionResolver                            IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /****/room/listByCompanyJSON - parameters:
extension: pdf
format: pdf
```

Code:

```
package com.company.pro

import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

import java.sql.Timestamp

import com.company.pro.constants.CommonSearchParams
import com.company.pro.constants.TicketType
import com.company.pro.decorator.JQGridDecorator
import com.company.pro.search.RoomSearch


class RoomController extends BaseController
{
    def debugOn = log.isDebugEnabled()

    static defaultAction = "list"

    def userService
    def inventoryJMSService
    def filterUtilService
    def accountJMSService
    def ticketingJMSService
    def minutesUntilStale =  5 //TODO: make this configurable?
    def millisUntilStale = minutesUntilStale * 60 * 1000

    def proExportService


    @Secured(['ROLE_TelePresenceReportUser'])
    def list(){
        def colNames="'${g.message( code:'common.status' )}','${g.message( code:'rooms.label' )}','${g.message( code:'user.details.site' )}','${g.message( code:'device.city' )}','${g.message( code:'common.stateProvince' )}','${g.message( code:'common.country' )}'"
        def colModel="{name:'status', editable: false, fixed: true, width:'60px'},{name:'room', editable: false, fixed: false, width:'200px'},{name:'siteName', editable: false, fixed: false, width:'350px'},{name:'city', editable: false, fixed:true, width:'125px'},{name:'state', editable: false, fixed: true, width:'150px'},{name:'country', editable: false, fixed: true, width:'150px'}"

        [colNames:colNames, colModel:colModel]
    }

    @Secured(['ROLE_TelePresenceReportUser'])
    def listJSON = {
        chain(action: 'listByCompanyJSON', params: params)
    }

    @Secured(['ROLE_TelePresenceReportUser'])
    def listByCompanyJSON = {
        params.companyId= filterUtilService.getCurrentCustomer()?.id
        params.monitoringStatus = CommonSearchParams.MONITORING

        if(params.format!=null && params.format != "html"){
                downloadList(session, params)

        }
        session.setAttribute("lastSearchParams", params)

        def findRoomsResponse = inventoryJMSService.findRooms(params)
        def search = new RoomSearch()
        search.params = params
        search.doSearch()
        session.setAttribute("lastRoomsSearch", search.data?.collect {it.room})
        def decorator = new JQGridDecorator(search)

        def data = decorator.asRoomsListGrid()

        def up = message(code:"status.up")
        def down = message(code:"status.down")
        data.rows.each {row -> row.cell[0] = row.cell[0] ? up : down }

        render data as JSON
    }

    private downloadList(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession session, Map params) {
        String cname = filterUtilService.getCurrentCustomer()?.name
        cname = cname.replaceAll(" ","_")
        def arrRooms =session.getAttribute("lastRoomsSearch")
        def deviceArray = getAllDevices().findAll { device -> arrRooms.find({currRoom ->  device.room == currRoom})}
        def siteMap = getSiteMap(deviceArray)

        deviceArray.each( {
            it.siteName = it.siteName?.split(":")[1];
        })
        //populate device array with site map
        deviceArray.each( {
            it.metaClass.city =  siteMap[it.siteId]?.city
            it.metaClass.state =  siteMap[it.siteId]?.state
            it.metaClass.country =  siteMap[it.siteId]?.country
            it.metaClass.countryAbbrev =  siteMap[it.siteId]?.countryAbbrev
            it.metaClass.companyId =  siteMap[it.siteId]?.companyId
            it.metaClass.companyName =  siteMap[it.siteId]?.companyName

        })

        def idList = deviceArray.collect({ it.deviceId})
        def arrId = idList.toArray(new String[0])
        //get url information for all device id's and populate that in deviceArray
        params.deviceIds =arrId
        params.populateSoldServices = false
        def respo2  = inventoryJMSService.findDevicesByKeys(params)
        def deviceByKeysSO = respo2.getDevices()
        deviceArray.each({
            def parentRec = it
            def record = deviceByKeysSO.find {parentRec.deviceId == it.deviceHeaderMgmtSysSO.deviceId}
            it.metaClass.deviceURL = record.deviceURL
            it.metaClass.region = record.region
            it.metaClass.floor = record.floor
        })

        List fields = ["city","state","companyId","companyName","countryAbbrev","country",
            "productCategorization.tier1","productCategorization.tier2","productCategorization.tier3",
            "deviceId", "deviceName","siteId", "siteName",
            "mgmtSysAddIPSO.description","mgmtSysAddIPSO.ipAddress",
            "mgmtSysAddIPSO.deviceExternalSysRefKey","mgmtSysAddIPSO.ipAddressTypeId",
            "deviceURL",
            "productCategorization.manufacturer","productCategorization.productModelVersion",
            "region","floor","room"
        ]



        Map labels =    ["city" : message(code:"device.city"),
            "state" : message(code:"common.stateProvince"),
            "companyId" : message(code:"reports.telepresence.cdr.columns.COMPANYID"),
            "companyName": message(code:"reports.telepresence.cdr.columns.COMPANYNAME"),
            "countryAbbrev" : message(code:"common.country.abbrev"),
            "country":message(code:"common.country"),
            "deviceId": message(code:"device.label.id"),
            "deviceName": message(code:"device.label.name"),
            "siteId": message(code:"common.siteId"),
            "siteName": message(code:"site.name"),
            "deviceURL" : message(code:"device.url"),
            "productCategorization.manufacturer": message(code:"device.detail.manufacturer"),
            "productCategorization.productModelVersion": message(code:"device.detail.model.version"),
            "region": message(code:"site.region"),
            "floor":message(code:"site.floor"),
            "room": message(code:"site.room")]

        Map parameters
        def title =  message(code:"rooms.label.plural") + "             " + message(code:"common.downloadDateTime") + " "+new Date()
            if(params.extension == TicketType.EXPORT_EXCEL){
             parameters = [title: title, "column.widths": [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2,0.2,0.2]]
             labels <<    ["productCategorization.tier1": message(code:"device.product.categorization.tier1"),
                           "productCategorization.tier2": message(code:"device.product.categorization.tier2"),
                           "productCategorization.tier3": message(code:"device.product.categorization.tier3"),
                           "mgmtSysAddIPSO.description": message(code:"device.mgmt.system"),
                           "mgmtSysAddIPSO.ipAddress": message(code:"device.mgmt.system.address"),
                           "mgmtSysAddIPSO.deviceExternalSysRefKey": message(code:"device.mgmt.system.refc"),
                           "mgmtSysAddIPSO.ipAddressTypeId": message(code:"device.mgmt.system.ipAddress.typid")]

             } else{
              parameters = [title: title]
              labels <<    ["productCategorization.tier1": message(code:"device.product.categorization.pc.tier1"),
                           "productCategorization.tier2": message(code:"device.product.categorization.pc.tier2"),
                           "productCategorization.tier3": message(code:"device.product.categorization.pc.tier3"),
                           "mgmtSysAddIPSO.description": message(code:"device.mgmt.sys"),
                           "mgmtSysAddIPSO.ipAddress": message(code:"device.mgmt.sys.address"),
                           "mgmtSysAddIPSO.deviceExternalSysRefKey": message(code:"device.mgmt.sys.refc"),
                           "mgmtSysAddIPSO.ipAddressTypeId": message(code:"device.mgmt.sys.ipAddress.typid")]
            }
             downloadDataToFiles(params.format, params.extension, "Room_List_" + cname,deviceArray, fields, labels, null, parameters)
        return
    }

    /**
     * This behavior has been moved to the JQGridDecorator object.
     * Must remove this later, when there is time to test thoroughly
     */
    private formatPanelResults={ findRoomsResponse ->
        session.setAttribute("lastRoomsSearch", findRoomsResponse?.collect {it.room})
        def allRows = findRoomsResponse?.collect {
            [
                    cell: [
                        it.status,
                        it.room,
                        it.siteName,
                        it.city,
                        it.state,
                        it.country
                        ],
                    id : it.room
            ]

        }.unique()

        def totalRows = allRows.size()
        def maxRows = Integer.valueOf(params.rows?:1)
        def currentPage = Integer.valueOf(params.page?:1)
        def numberOfPages = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows).toInteger()
        def rowOffset = ((currentPage - 1) * maxRows)

        def maxIndex = rowOffset + maxRows
        if (maxIndex > totalRows ) { maxIndex = totalRows }

        [rows:allRows, records: totalRows, page: currentPage, total:numberOfPages]

    }
    @Secured(['ROLE_TelePresenceReportUser'])
    def listDevicesByRoomJSON() {
        if (params.room == null) {render ''}

        def devicesForRoom = getRoomDeviceList().findAll { it.room == params.room }

        if (debugOn) log.debug('devicesForRoom: ' + devicesForRoom)

        def totalRows = devicesForRoom.size()
        def maxRows = Integer.valueOf(params.rows?:1)
        def currentPage = Integer.valueOf(params.page?:1)
        def numberOfPages = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows).toInteger()
        def rowOffset = ((currentPage - 1) * maxRows)

        def maxIndex = rowOffset + maxRows
        if (maxIndex > totalRows ) {maxIndex = totalRows}
        if (debugOn) log.debug ("totalRows: $totalRows, maxRows: $maxRows, currentPage: $currentPage, numberOfPages: $numberOfPages, rowOffset: $rowOffset, maxIndex: $maxIndex")
        def roleArr = session.getAttribute("roles")
        def svcRole = roleArr.findAll{ it.name.equalsIgnoreCase('RequestServiceUser')}
        def validRoleExists = false
        if(svcRole.size == 1)
            validRoleExists = true

        def rows = devicesForRoom[rowOffset ..< maxIndex].collect() {
            [
                cell: [
                    it.deviceId,
                    it.deviceName,
                    it.status?'Up':'Down',
                    "<a href=" + createLink(controller:'requestService', action:'create',absolute:true, params:[thisDevice:it.deviceId, requestType:14, showDevSel:false]) + ">" + message(code:'default.button.create.label') + "</href>"
                ],
                id:it.deviceId
            ]
        }

        def jsonData = [rows:rows, records: totalRows, page: currentPage, total:numberOfPages,showSvcReq:validRoleExists]
        render jsonData as JSON
    }

    private uniqueRoomData() {
        def deviceList = getRoomDeviceList()
        def downRooms = deviceList.findAll { !it.status }.collect { it.room }
        if (debugOn) log.debug("downRooms: $downRooms")

        /* Added the below code for Download functionality */

            //for the room list, we do not want device data
            def temp = deviceList?.collect {
                [
                    'status' : downRooms.contains(it.room) ? 'Down' : 'Up' ,
                    'room' : it.room,
                    'siteName' : it.siteName,
                    'city' : it.city,
                    'state' : it.state,
                    'country' : it.country
                ]
            }

            temp = sortList(temp)

            //if more than one device in a room, there will be duplicate data. Remove it.
            def rows = temp.unique().collect {
                [
                    cell: [
                        it.status,
                        it.room,
                        it.siteName,
                        it.city,
                        it.state,
                        it.country
                        ],
                    id : it.room
                ]

            }

    }
    private sortList(list) {
        def asc = params['sord']=='asc'
        def idx = params['sidx']
        if (asc) {
            return list.sort { a, b ->
                a[idx].compareToIgnoreCase(b[idx])
            }
        }
        else {
            return list.sort { a, b ->
                b[idx].compareToIgnoreCase(a[idx])
            }
        }
    }

    private getRoomDeviceList() {
        def roomDeviceList = session.getAttribute("roomDeviceList")
        def roomDeviceListCreated = session.getAttribute("roomDeviceListCreated")
        def refreshNeeded = false
        //check for null or stale list
        if (roomDeviceList != null && roomDeviceListCreated != null) {
            def now = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
            refreshNeeded = (now - roomDeviceListCreated > millisUntilStale)
        }
        else {
            //roomDeviceList or roomDeviceListCreated *is* null, generate new list
            refreshNeeded = true
        }
        if(debugOn) log.debug( "refreshNeeded: " + refreshNeeded)
        if (refreshNeeded) roomDeviceList = populateRoomDeviceListForSession()
        if(debugOn) log.debug('roomDeviceList: ' + roomDeviceList?:"<null>")
        return roomDeviceList
    }

    private populateRoomDeviceListForSession() {
        //def devices = devicesInRooms(getAllDevices())
        def devices = getAllDevices().findAll { it.room }
        def alarmMap = getAlarmMap()
        def siteMap = getSiteMap (devices)

        def results = devices?.collect {            
            [
                room : it.room,
                deviceId : it.deviceId,
                deviceName : it.deviceName,
                siteName : it.siteName == null ? null: it.siteName.substring(it.siteName.indexOf(":")+1), //strip companyId & ':' from site name,
                city : siteMap[it.siteId].city,
                state : siteMap[it.siteId].state,
                country : siteMap[it.siteId].country,
                status:!(alarmMap?.values()?.contains(it.deviceId))
                //status: message(code:alarmMap.values().contains(it.deviceId)?'status.down':'status.up')
            ]       
        }

        session.setAttribute("roomDeviceList", results)
        session.setAttribute("roomDeviceListCreated",new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        return results
    }

    private getAllDevices() {
        //AuthenticatedUser usr = springSecurityService.getPrincipal()
        params.companyId= filterUtilService.getCurrentCustomer()?.id //usr.getCompanyId()
        params.totalDeviceCountNeeded=true
        params.monitoringStatus = CommonSearchParams.MONITORING
        def tempRowParam = params.rows //need to store this value - will restore it later
        params.rows = 9999 //we need all devices to find those with rooms...
        def resp = inventoryJMSService.searchDevices(params)
        params.rows = tempRowParam //restore original value so that pagination will work properly on first call
        log.info("getAllDevices params:$params")
        return resp?.getSearchDevices()

    }

    private getSiteMap(devices) {
        String[] siteIds = (devices*.siteId).unique()
        def siteMap = [:]
        if (!siteIds) {
            return siteMap
        }
        def resp = accountJMSService.findSitesByKeys([siteIds:siteIds])
        resp?.sites?.each {
                    siteMap.put(it.id, [
                        name: it.name == null ? null: it.name.substring(it.name.indexOf(":")+1), //strip companyId & ':' from site name, 
                        city:it.city, 
                        state:it.stateProvince, 
                        //country:it.countryAbbrev,//updated
                        countryAbbrev:it.countryAbbrev,
                        country:it.country,
                        companyId: it.companyId,
                        companyName:it.companyName
                    ]
                )
            }
            if (debugOn) log.debug(siteMap)


        return siteMap

    }

    private getAlarmMap() {
        def tempRowParam = params.rows //need to store this value - will restore it later
        params.rows = 9999
        if (debugOn) log.debug("getAlarmMap params: $params")

        def resp = ticketingJMSService.searchAlapro([companyId:params.companyId, monitoringStatus:CommonSearchParams.MONITORING, ticketState: 'OPEN'])
        def map = [:]
        params.rows = tempRowParam //restore original value so that pagination will work properly on first call
        log.info("getAlarmMap params:$params")
        resp?.alapro?.each {
                map.put(it.id, it.deviceId)
            }
            if (debugOn) log.debug("getAlarmMap map: $map")

        return map
    }

    def listAll = {
        def customer = filterUtilService.getCurrentCustomer()?.id
        def search = new RoomSearch(customer)
        render search.parseDataAsJSON() as JSON
    }

    def lastSearchFullDataset = {
        def params = session.getAttribute("lastSearchParams");
        params.loadonce = true
        def search = new RoomSearch()
        search.params = params
        search.doSearch()

        render search.data as JSON
    }

    def getRoomsByGroup = {

        def rooms = []
            def group = params.group=='Group 1'?'0':'1'
            getAllDevices().collect{
                if(group == it.group){
                    if(it.room !=null && it.room.trim() !="" && it.room.trim().length()>0){
                        rooms.add(it.room)
                    }
                }
            }
        render rooms as JSON
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: It's not clear from provided code sample what method throws this exception. Please provide more details, and please remove all unrelated code.

Answer (score 3):

When you directly rendering things let grails know not to render the view. Use:

```
//outputStream - make sure you close it
OutputStream out
try {
    out = response.getOutputStream()
    out << bytes
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    //gulp - can't send to the browser
} finally {
    try {   
        out?.close()
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        //gulp - can't close
    }
}
//or render input stream
    render ( file: <InputStream>, contentType: '<content/type>')
//or render byte array
    render ( file: <byte[]>, contentType: '<content/type>')
//or just tell Grails that you don't want the view rendered.
    GrailsWebRequest webRequest = 
             (GrailsWebRequest) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
    webRequest.setRenderView(false)
```

Let me know if it works for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

You `listByCompanyJSON` have an error: you should stop processing request and making a new response after calling `downloadList`:

```
if(params.format!=null && params.format != "html"){
    downloadList(session, params)
    return // <-- like this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this issue: [User cancelled file download in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323850/user-cancelled-file-download-in-grails), might be helpful as possibly you get second request while first is still serving and ClientAbortException is thrown.